# Minecraft screen bug

Tags: screen, minecraft

im new to askubuntu and I need some help on fixing some bug in ubuntu 11.10 / Minecraft 1.0.1 (also happene in previous versions). The bug is: screen flashes, everything flickering, hand signs and chest flashing black. The bug is so bad that is preventing me to play the game. Please help. I have an ATI graphics card, intel i5 quad-core processor.

Comment: Which video card drivers are you using - the default ones, the ones that show up in the  restricted hardware drivers section of the system settings, or something else?

Comment: are you using openjdk or java?